# AWS service AWSSupportDeveloper. What is this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, billing

I've looked through a CloudWatch billing metrics list and found a service that costs 50$ but I don't know what **AWSSupportDeveloper** is. Google can not help me or I just don't know how to ask it :).

Can anybody share a link or give some information about this service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Developer-level AWS support is $49/month](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/). I don't know where the extra dollar is from, but I know that's the line item.